# Can't run function by checking domain

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, youtube

I want a video in youtube playlist to skip to the next video when it reaches 2:41 seconds.

It works when I run the domain control separately, it works when I run the function separately.

It doesn't work together, why? I cannot run the function by checking the domain with `window.location.href`.

```js
function generateCount(limit) {
   const counterEle = document.querySelector("video");
   if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {
        document
          .querySelector(
            "#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button"
          )
          .click();

        setInterval(generateCount, 3000, limit);
     }
}

if (
      window.location.href ==
      "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93qE6Z8qheA&list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17&index=5"
    ) {
      generateCount(160.510023);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the URL is incorrect? When I go to your link, I get retirected to `index=6` (same video ID though, maybe the playlist order changed?)

Answer (score 0):

When you first run your code, you call your `generateCount(160.510023);` function, which checks the current time on the video. If this runs when your page initially loads, the video player will have a time that is less than `160.510023`, and so your if-statement condition will evaluate to `false` and your script will finish. Instead, start your interval timer when your page loads rather than when you move to the next video. This way you can repeatedly call `generateCount` for the first video, which will then repeatedly check the current video time:

```js
function generateCount(limit) {
  const counterEle = document.querySelector("video");
  if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {
    document
      .querySelector(
        "#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button"
      )
      .click();
  }
}

if (window.location.href == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93qE6Z8qheA&list=PL9dIg-VwAsxZdZvuHjzTOP8-49CWpis17&index=5") {
  setInterval(generateCount, 3000, 160.510023);
}
```

As youtube is a SPA this code will run even after the redirection occurs to the next video. If you only want this to run for your first video, you can call your `generatetCount()` function normally in your first if-statement that checks the url, and then use `setTimeout()` to queue a new call to `generateCount()` after ~3s to recheck the current video time if the current time is smaller than (or equal to) the limit:

```
function generateCount(limit) {
  const counterEle = document.querySelector("video");
  if (counterEle.currentTime > limit) {
    ...
  } else {
    setTimeout(generateCount, 3000, limit);
  }
}

if (...) {
  generateCount(160.510023);
}
```